# Routing Choices in the Balkans

Tags: driving, borders, montenegro, bosnia, kosovo

I'm going from Kosovo to Bosnia by road. Should I go through Montenegro because the Serbian government does not recognize Kosovo? Or can I pass through Serbia because I am not a citizen of Kosovo? And Does the Montenegrin government pose problems like Serbia? There is visa liberalization for all three countries.

Answer (score 1):

If you're not a citizen of Kosovo, you cannot enter Serbia from Kosovo (https://wikitravel.org/en/Kosovo), unless you've also previously entered Kosovo from Serbia.